# Images are not binding in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working in xamarin.forms. Local images are not binding. The image folder[image]

code to retrieving image is

```
    public const string RESOURCE_CIRCLE = "RadioCheckNoPlugin.Controls.Resources.circle.png";
public const string RESOURCE_DOT = "RadioCheckNoPlugin.Controls.Resources.dot.png";

public IconView iconCircle = new IconView { Source = ImageSource.FromResource(RESOURCE_CIRCLE), FillColor = GlobalSetting.BorderColor, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HeightRequest = GlobalSetting.Size, WidthRequest = GlobalSetting.Size };
public IconView iconChecked = new IconView { Source = ImageSource.FromResource(RESOURCE_DOT), FillColor = GlobalSetting.Color, IsVisible = false, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, HeightRequest = GlobalSetting.Size, WidthRequest = GlobalSetting.Size };
```

Image property **Build Action:Embedded resource** and I am not getting any errors. I tried by removing .png extension also but it's not binding.
Please help me with how to bind images.

Comment: If you look at the item properties for one of those images, does the resource id match the ones that you are using as consts?

Comment: @SushiHangover yes it matches.

Comment: Try changing `public const string RESOURCE_DOT = "RadioCheckNoPlugin.Controls.Resources.dot.png";` to `RESOURCE_DOT = dot.png`

Comment: @lawiluk sorry it is not working.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows adding an image should be as simple as that:
`var image = new Image { Source = "waterfront.jpg" };` No need for ImageSource.

Comment: @lawiluk, sorry not working

Comment: @SagarPatil If I were you I would set the background of this image and see if it's being rendered (maybe GlobalSetting.Size is or null?). Secondly, I would change IconView to the Image to check if the problem is in IconView or with my resources. In the next step, if it still does not work, I will remove the images from the project, add them again & clean solution. For sure you need to get it working for a simple image. Later you can try changing it to IconView

Answer (score 0):

Change your image path constants as below :

```
public const string RESOURCE_CIRCLE = "resource://RadioCheckNoPlugin.Controls.Resources.circle.png";
public const string RESOURCE_DOT = "resource://RadioCheckNoPlugin.Controls.Resources.dot.png";
```